# SQL - To load into memory, or to query database

Tags: c#, sql-server, memory

I'm interested in your opinions, best thoughts ...
Would you say it's better to just query the database any time you want to retrieve data (even if you know it'll be static), or store the data in server(web) session memory?

On the one hand, storing in memory would allow faster processing of data, and decrease SQL server loads.  On the other hand, it can somewhat increase complication of application code, and web server/system resources.

Comment: For static data, consider lazy loading, for non static data, consider last modification date comparison.

Comment: Using a cache framework doesn't increase a lot of complexity, especially if you are positive you will never have to invalidate the cache.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends (as most do) on your specific needs. If your database has the bandwidth but your web server doesn't, you should do it in SQL. And vice versa. There's no way to recommend anything to anyone without knowing their situation.

Comment: Thank you.  It's a general, best practices question, so I don't really have a specific situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use static dictionaries to store static data from database.

The benefit of use this is have only one instance of each dictionary and reduce the number of request to the database.

You can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283877/using-static-dictionary-instead-of-session-asp-net-mvc) to see how to implement this.

Comment: What if the data does change?  How would the app know to reload the cached data?  A query to the database to determine if the table has been updated?  I guess this would be good if there is a lot of table data to be retrieved, but not so much if you are only worried about small chunks of data.

Comment: In fact this is useful with small chunks of static data that like country names for example.